# MS Access @@identity query issue

Tags: sql, ms-access

Can someone please let me know the issue with the below query? I am running on MS Access and its giving

> Syntax error in query expression 'id = @@IDENTITY'

Code:

```
public DosageBO SaveDosage(DosageBO dosage)
{
   try
   {
      using (IDbConnection connection = OpenConnection())
      {
         StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
         sql.AppendLine("INSERT INTO dosage_master ( medicine_type, dosage, remarks, updateby, updatedate )");
         sql.AppendLine("VALUES (@type, @dose, @remarks, @updateby, NOW());");

         var parameters = new
                    {
                        type = dosage.MedicineType,
                        dose = dosage.Dosage,
                        remarks = dosage.Remarks,
                        updateby = Environment.UserName
                    };

         connection.Execute(sql.ToString(), parameters);

         return connection.Query<DosageBO>("SELECT medicine_type as MedicineType, dosage, remarks FROM dosage_master WHERE id = @@IDENTITY").FirstOrDefault();
      }
   }
   catch
   {
      throw;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT @@Identity` is a specialized query.  And `@@Identity` is only valid in that context.  If you attempt to use `@@Identity` elsewhere, as in a `WHERE` clause, the db engine will throw an error.

You will have to retrieve the value from `SELECT @@Identity`, save it, and then use that saved value in your other query.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `)` at the end

```
WHERE id = @@IDENTITY) 
                     ^---here
```

Comment: It still gives the same issue.

Comment: I think its a short coming of Access DB.

Answer (score 0):

Are you inserting a row in this batch prior to the select query?
To my knowledge @@IDENTITY is only available directly after inserting a row causing an identity value to be generated i.e an insert to an autoincremental identity column.

Edit again: 
Try enclosing it in a subquery e.g `id = (SELECT @@IDENTITY)`

Comment: Yes I am inserting a row and since its a Autonumber I am using @@identity to fetch the last id and querying the same table again to get all the data.

Comment: MS access doesn't allows to run multiple query at the same time. If I just query SELECT @@IDENTITY it returns the proper identity value. So your above suggestion won't work. Till my knowledge when we write id = @@identity, it considers as a multiple query and so giving exception. Anyways open for suggestion and workaround.

Comment: Before posting the query I even tried that but it doesn't works since its multiple query.